# Adding UINavigationController to root UIViewController using addChildViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, hierarchy

What I want to do is have a root view controller that manages the base view of my application and then add a UINavigationViewController (with its own view controller stack) to that view controller using the iOS 5+ containment API addChildViewController().

EDIT: The purpose of the base view controller is to control a dynamic view that is a consistent background across the application. There are animations involved so the actual background view needs to stay the same across every view.

My question is whether this is a best practice and the Apple-approved way to accomplish such a design? I have been reading conflicting advice in my research and want to make sure my app will not be rejected.

Here is the code from my AppDelegate, which shows what I am trying to do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
   BaseViewController * base = [[BaseViewController alloc] init];

   PlayerViewController * player = [[PlayerViewController alloc] init];
   UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:player];
   [nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

   [base addChildViewController:nav];
   [base.view addSubview:nav.view];

   [self.window setRootViewController:base];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of BaseViewController? It's not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: The BaseViewController is a GLKViewController that is consistent across all views, but dynamically changing and accepting touch events.

Comment: Wouldn't be much easier to use the UINavigationController as the root of your app and all the view controllers that are pushed on the stack would extend your `GLKViewController` in this way you will have a consistent background across the app and also you can change, if you want the functionality of your `GLKViewController ` in some cases.

Comment: @danypata - if I were to do that, then the background would need re-instantiated upon each view controller loading, so it would not be consistent. There are animations involved. I suppose that is relevant information.

Comment: @JimDaniel Yep that's an important info ;)

Comment: Also, the app won't be rejected because of your controller stack/structure. Apple provides you a range of controllers with properties/method to use and doesn't care about how your app is structured as long as you don't use private API methods to create your structure.